# Batch update in Hibernate4

Tags: hibernate, batch-processing

I want to perform batch update for a query. Here are the 4 queries which I want to perform in batch processing :

```
Update Contact SET contactNumber = '876-128-9871' WHERE userId = 1 AND contactType = 'A';
Update Contact SET contactNumber = '615-165-9071' WHERE userId = 1 AND contactType = 'B';
Update Contact SET contactNumber = '816-897-5818' WHERE userId = 1 AND contactType = 'C';
Update Contact SET contactNumber = '151-891-7861' WHERE userId = 1 AND contactType = 'D';
```

Is it possible to perform batch update for such scenario?

If yes then how?

Any reference/link appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly you just would like to make a DML style batch processing. Here is the official tutorial about it: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.0/manual/en-US/html/batch.html